# SELECT into structured object with ABAP CDS associations

Tags: abap, opensql, cds

I have a CDS View with multiple associations:

```
define view ZORDER as select from ZORDERHDR as orderHdr
association [0..1] to ZORDER_LOCATION as _location on _location.orderID = orderHdr.orderID
association [0..*] to ZORDER_ITEM as _items on _items.orderID = orderHdr.orderID
association [0..*] to ZORDER_PARTNER as _partners on _partners.orderID = orderHdr.orderID
```

Now, I would like to select from the view a single order and get a result something like this:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF t_order,
         header TYPE zorderhdr,
         location TYPE zorder_location,
         items TYPE zorder_items, "This is a table type
        END OF t_order.
```

Is there a SELECT statement that can read all the order into a nested structure like the one above?

Edit: I added a second 0..* association to ensure that the proposed solution doesn't suggest to select everything and then reduce the header and location to their structures. The problem I see is that with complex CDS views I seem to need to handle all the associations with custom code like I would do if it was normal OpenSQL, then I lose the benefit of the CDS views model design (when not consuming from Gateway) and I select too much data.

Comment: Are you consuming the data using a OData service? If yes, you could use the `$expand` parameter to only fill `zorder_items`. My guess is, that debugging the relevant autogenerated DPC methods might be helpful.

Comment: Hi Konstantin. No, actually the question point is how to benefit from the CDS model when you consume it directly in ABAP using OpenSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do SELECT like this. If you right click the CDS view, and click "**Show SQL CREATE Statement**", you should see it as a regular database SQL view. 
and it is a `JOIN` if you expose the fields from your association. You open the `@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'YOURSQLVIEW'` by **SE11**, it is a flat structure.

One of the benefit of CDS view modeling with `ASSOCIATION` instead of `JOIN` is that you have the navigation generated if you include the CDS as datasource to your Gateway project. then you can have the URL navigation like zorderhdr/to_item to get all the items or like `zorderhdr/to_item(item_key)` to get one item.

One more thing, for transactional CDS view, you can [generate a BOPF object](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/09/20/fioriui5-cds-bopf-for-beginners/) by modeling the node hierarchy using `ASSOCIATION` .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know the view ends up being a flat structure, but I was hoping there was a way to simulate the full or partial tree navigation with a SELECT statement, I think SAP could make it possible. I'm aware of the BOPF generation but I couldn't try it properly since in 7.50 the BOPF framework was giving me a lot of problems, even though I see the blog you pointed is actually for 7.50. Now I'm curious how the BOPF does the selection of a single BO with all it's child associations, maybe I could use the idea

Comment: i have deep experience with CDS based BOPF. in case any question, please ask in SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

I think you can address all fields of `_items` with `_items~*` in your select clause, but it's like a flat regular JOIN.

(Sidenote: your concept would map nicely to [ABAP meshes](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenabap_meshes.htm) if it were supported)

Comment: OK, thanks. I will wait a bit before accepting your answer, just in case someone else has a proposal.  Regarding the meshes, yes, actually what I would expect is that you can generate an ABAP mesh from a CDS view with associations after you select with Open SQL